# No SSH access to EC2 instance launched by ASG, while I can access an otherwise identical instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to SSH to an EC2 instance that's part of an ASG associated with an ECS service. To help narrow down the problem, I created new instance from the same launch template. I've carefully verified that I used the same template version, and even manually paged through and validated that everything (other than unique elements like IP addresses, etc.) is identical: same key pair, VPC, subnet, availability zone, security group, IAM role.

The only difference I see is the associated ASG and the second network interface.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions or guidance on how to troubleshoot this. If there are good resources somebody can point me to, I'm happy to RTFM, but so far I've been a little lost in the AWS documentation labyrinth.

Edit:
To add some context, I've also noticed that the container task I'm running via the ECS service will start correctly the first time I run it on a newly created EC2 instance, but then will not subsequently start at all (no logs or events are emitted--it just hangs in pending). To me, this suggests that it may be either the ECS agent or the task itself that's disrupting both the SSH connect and these subsequent task executions. I'll try deploying a dummy container to a newly provisioned EC2 instance. If that doesn't disrupt SSH, it would suggest that the issue related to the actual task I'm running.

Comment: Show `ssh -v` output.

Comment: ssh -i ~/.ssh/<my_key>.pem -vvv ec2user@<IP>
    OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
    [...]
    debug1: Connecting to <IP> [<IP>] port 22.
    debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
    debug1: connect to address <IP> port 22: Operation timed out
    ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Operation timed out

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by increasing the storage for the instance. In this case, from 30 to 60 GB. The image(s) are quite large (~15 GB) and also downloads an additional model on initialization. I was trying to debug a separate issue by trying two alternate versions of an image, leading to the storage quickly filling up and causing problems.